# A good user forum extension for Joomla?

Tags: joomla

Does anybody knows a good Joomla user forum extension?

Answer (score 1):

I'd also suggest Kunena forum as a good Joomla native extension. I can also confirm there are many, though, that prefer to run a different forum site on a non-Joomla platform, with a bridge for shared authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Kunena](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum/7256) on multiple sites, it's nice and really simple and is built for Joomla. There are also [bridges](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum-bridges) for stand alone forums like phpBB, etc. Hope that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

use Vanilla forums for Joomla, also engage interaction using PHPBB3 bridges with Joomla